# Brainfuck interpreter strange output

Tags: c++, interpreter, vcl, c++builder-6, brainfuck

I've decided to write a simple Brainfuck IDE in C++ using Borland's CppBuilder6. I've put on my for a RichEdit and made it look somewhat like notepad. Then I've added TEdit for input and TMemo for output. After some tests, I thought that RichEdit is bad component to use in my case and I changed it to TMemo.

In my code input = Edit2, code = Memo2, output = Memo1. I rewrote it two times and this version seems most correct; I've decided to not use pointers (i thought about it and even wrote pointer version, unfortunately it didn't work too so for simplifying I've removed pointers).

```
char *cells = (char*)calloc(65536,1); //Should i use malloc?
int cellp = 0;
void __fastcall BFIde::interpret() {
        char* pf = Memo2->Lines->Text.c_str(); //Weird output
        char* p = (char*)malloc(strlen(pf)+1);
        strcpy(p, pf); //Because pf is constant, i need to copy it into not constant string.
        int pp = 0;

        MessageBox(NULL,p,NULL,MB_OK); //To ensure that program is correct, but it ain't.

        while(p[pp]){
                switch(p[pp]){
                        case '>':
                                cellp++;
                                break;
                        case '<':
                                cellp--;
                                break;
                        case '+':
                                MessageBox(NULL, "Plus", NULL, MB_OK); //When executing test code, never gets shown.
                                cells[cellp]++;
                                break;
                        case '-':
                                cells[cellp]--;
                                break;
                        case '.':{ //It should look other, but I've replaced it to ensure that output is correct.
                                char arr[2]={cells[cellp],0};MessageBox(NULL, arr, NULL, MB_OK);}
                                break;
                        case ',': //Remove first character and pass it to program
                                if(Edit2->Text == "")cells[cellp] = 0;
                                else {cells[cellp] = Edit2->Text.c_str()[0];char* str;strcpy(str, Edit2->Text.c_str());Edit2->Text=str++;}
                                break;
                        case '[':{ //Propably works.
                                int bal = 1;
                                if (cells[cellp] == '\0') {
                                        do {
                                                pp++;
                                                if      (p[pp] == '[') bal++;
                                                else if (p[pp] == ']') bal--;
                                        } while ( bal != 0 );
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        case ']':
                                int bal2 = 0;
                                do {
                                        if      (p[pp] == '[') bal2++;
                                        else if (p[pp] == ']') bal2--;
                                        pp--;
                                } while ( bal2 != 0 );
                                break;
                }
                pp++;
        }
        MessageBox(NULL, IntToStr(cellp).c_str(), NULL, MB_OK); //To check that something was parsed. Shows 0 everytime (not expected).
}
```

When i enter some code, eg. "+." and execute this function (via button), this shows series of messagebox. First: `┼` (line 8), second: `0` (line 55), and nothing more shows. Expected result was to write: First `+.`, second `Plus`, and empty 3rd. What I've made wrong in my code? Maybe I've missed something.

Comment: And what have you done so far to debug this yourself?  StackOverflow is not a debugging service.  You have an expected result, so step through your code with the debugger until it deviates from that expectation, and then you can figure out why it deviates. But I can tell you right now, your overzealous use of `Text.c_str()` is very wrong, but especially the first one: `char* pf = Memo2->Lines->Text.c_str(); char* p = (char*)malloc(strlen(pf)+1); strcpy(p, pf);`. Why do you think that is wrong? I will give you a hint - it has UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR!

Comment: @RemyLebeau Have you ever used c++builder6 debugger?

Comment: All the time. BCB6 is the compiler I have to use at my day job :-(  But the issue you describe is not limited to just BCB6.  You have errors in your code, so it would be broken in any compiler version.

Comment: bcb6 debugger shown me error at end of caller procedure.

Comment: There are errors in your code, starting with the *very first line* of your `interpret()` function. Do you understand WHY that line of code is faulty? You are taking a pointer to temporary data that gets freed immediately after you take the pointer, so the subsequent lines of code are operating on invalid memory. There is another memory error in your `','` handler - you are trying to copying data to an uninitialized pointer that is not pointing at valid memory.

Comment: So i've figured it out before, by an accident (...), thanks for clarifying. I'll try out fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are memory-related errors in your code.  The very first line of `interpret()` is taking a pointer to a temporary `AnsiString` that is freed immediately afterwards, so the subsequent lines of code are operating with a dangling pointer to invalid memory.  Likewise, in your `','` handler, you are trying to copy data to an uninitialized pointer that is not pointing at valid memory.  And you are not doing any bounds checking when accessing your `cells[]` array.

There are also logic errors in your `']'` handler.  You are not checking the current cell data for 0 to decide which instruction to jump to next, and you are not seeking backwards correctly when looking for the opening `'['`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
static const int maxCells = 65536;

class BFIde : public TForm
{
__published:
    TEdit *Edit2;
    TMemo *Memo1;
    TMemo *Memo2;
    TButton *Button1;
    void __fastcall Button1(TObject *Sender);
private:
    char cells[maxCells];
    int cellp;
    char& cellData();
    void __fastcall interpret(const AnsiString &commands, AnsiString input);
public:
    __fastcall BFIde(TComponent *Owner);
};
```

```
__fastcall BFIde::BFIde(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}

char& __fastcall BFIde::cellData()
{
    if ((cellp < 0) or (cellp >= maxCells))
        throw Exception("Accessing cells out of bounds");
    return cells[cellp];
}

void __fastcall BFIde::interpret(const AnsiString &commands, AnsiString input)
{
    Memo1->Clear();

    memset(cells, 0, maxCells);
    cellp = 0;

    const char* start = commands.c_str();
    const char* p = start;

    while (*p)
    {
        switch (*p)
        {
            case '>':
                ++cellp;
                break;

            case '<':
                --cellp;
                break;

            case '+':
                cellData()++;
                break;

            case '-':
                cellData()--;
                break;

            case '.':
            {
                char ch = cellData();
                Memo1->SelStart = Memo1->GetTextLen();
                Memo1->SelLength = 0;
                Memo1->SelText = ch;
                break;
            }

            case ',':
            {
                char ch;
                if (input.Length() == 0) {
                    ch = '\0';
                }
                else {
                    ch = input[1];
                    input.Delete(1, 1);
                }
                cellData() = ch;
                break;
            }

            case '[':
            {
                if (cellData() == '\0')
                {
                    int bal = 1;
                    while (*++p)
                    {
                        if (*p == '[') {
                            ++bal;
                        }
                        else if (*p == ']')
                        {
                            if (--bal == 0)
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (bal != 0)
                        throw Exception("Unbalanced loop");
                }
                break;
            }

            case ']':
            {
                if (cellData() != '\0')
                {
                    int bal = 1;
                    while (p > start)
                    {
                        --p;
                        if (*p == ']') {
                            ++bal;
                        }
                        else if (*p == '[')
                        {
                            if (--bal == 0)
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (bal != 0)
                        throw Exception("Unbalanced loop");
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        ++p;
    }

    ShowMessage(cellp);
}

void __fastcall BFIde::Button1(TObject *Sender)
{
    interpret(Memo2->Lines->Text,  Edit2->Text);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about GetTextLen(), your code is ok. Thank you very much.